# Can a line integral be written as a multiple of two scalars.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

I'm trying to figure out if the following equality is true:

$$ \int_C \vec{v} \cdot d\vec{r} = \int_C \left\lVert \vec{v} \right\rVert ds$$

I figured that $d\vec{r} = \vec{T}ds$, where $\vec{T}$ is the tangent of the curve at a given point and $ds = \left\lVert d\vec{r} \right\rVert$.

So I get:

$$\int_C \vec{v} \cdot d\vec{r} = \int_C \vec{v} \cdot \vec{T} ds$$

I have been told that the initial equality is true. However, how can it be true if $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{T}$ is only equal to the magnitude of $\vec{v}$ if the vector is completely along the tangent? Can't the vector v point in a different direction.

Comment: "I have been told that the initial equality is true" Who said that?

Comment: A very unreliable source it seems. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no.

It may be clarifying to look at the definitions.

Suppose $\vec r:[a,b]\to C$ is a parametrization of the smooth path. Then

$$
\int_C \vec v\cdot d\vec r=\int_a^b \vec v\cdot \vec r'(t)\,dt
$$

$$
\int_C \|\vec v\|\,ds=\int_a^b \|\vec v(t)\|\cdot \|\vec r'(t)\|\,dt
$$

But the second integral is always nonnegative.

---

Consider $\vec r(t)=(t,0)$ and $\vec v\equiv(-1,0)$ for $t\in[0,1]$. Then
$$
\int_C \vec v\cdot d\vec r=\int_0^1 -1\,dt,\quad
\int_C \|\vec v\|\,ds=\int_0^11\,dt
$$